# Unity Json cannot serialize a generic list

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am attempting to write a method that takes in an object and will use the Unity JsonUtility or the [JsonHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity) and returns the serialized version of that object. When I run the below debugging code everything works correctly.

```
    object t = new List<Player>
    {
        new Player
        {
            Name = "asdf",
            ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        }
    };

    if (t is IEnumerable<Player> list)
        Debug.Log(JsonHelper.ToJson(list.ToArray()));

//Result {"Items":[{"ID":"eff6ca08-b464-4e57-9f2e-f49a0cb869ff","Name":"asdf"}]}
```

However, my actual method does not return the same thing.

```
 public void SeriailizeObject<T>(T obj)
 {
    if (obj is IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        Debug.Log(JsonHelper.ToJson(list.ToArray()));
        //Result {}
    }
    ...
```

Does anyone know if you can serialize a generic list with Unity's JsonUtility?

Comment: `T` can never be `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay can you expand on that? When I debug the method, I do enter the if statement.

Comment: It would cause an infinitely recursive structure. Think about it, if `T` is `IEnumerable<T>` what is `T`?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `SeriailizeObject(new List<Player>())`, `typeof(T)` is equal to `List<Player>` and `obj` is *not* an `IEnumerable<List<Player>>`.

When calling `SeriailizeObject(t)`, `typeof(T)` is equal to `object` and `obj` is an `IEnumerable<object>` (assuming that `t` is a `List<Player>`).